# How to Create Select field in Magento

Tags: magento, module

I want to create a select field in magento system.xml, and calling a model from that but getting error. My code is...

```
<banner_type translate="label">
                            <label>Banner Type</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                     <source_model>banners/bannertype</source_model>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <comment>(If you select banner type, then display with that type!)</comment>
 </banner_type>
```

**Error:**

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in /var/www/html/imran/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 399
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento attempting to instantiate a model class

```
Mage::getModel('banners/bannertype')
```

so it can it's `toOptionArray` method.  However, in your system `banners/bannertype` doesn't resolve to a valid model class, so PHP complains.

Comment: Hi, Alan Storm, i am following your article on system.xml. but it the same is your..

Comment: Thanx, alot Alan Storm, i fix it. bcz i am not following the model class way, because this is my first editing to Magento anyway, but i fix it by Capital the first letter of model class. Now i want to get that configuration on frontend and display appropriate phtml for banners...

Comment: @ime interesting topic, could you please share us the complete pack? what did you do and what did you get. thanks

Comment: it, simply Check the banner type, and display banner according to that settings. and load phtml for specific type banner. i have not done yet, so no totally idea of implementation yet..